# R Words Error: Failed to prepare query: Error: column "obs" does not exist

Tags: r, wrds

I am trying to use WRDS with R by using this code:
[image]

I am getting this error:

[image]

I tried removing (obs=10) and I did not receive the same error, but when I entered:

[image]

The result was:

[image]

I tried this:

[image]

and got the same error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please don’t use images of code or data as they cannot be used without a lot of unnecessary effort. [For multiple reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). You’re more likely to get a positive response if your question is reproducible. [See Stack Overflow question guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `dbFetch` rather than `fetch`.

res <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "SELECT date, dji FROM djones.djdaily")

data <- dbFetch(res, n = -1)

Comment: Your answer could be improved by providing an example of the solution and how it helps the OP.

Comment: res <- dbSendQuery(wrds, "SELECT date, dji FROM djones.djdaily")
data <- dbFetch(res, n = -1)

Answer (score 0):

I would say that approaches using `dplyr`/`dbplyr` are better when working with the WRDS PostgreSQL database.

To do the equivalent of `(obs=10)`, do something like the following. The real payoff to `dbplyr`-based approaches comes when merging multiple large tables, which happens on the WRDS PostgreSQL server without needing to download data.

For many more examples like this one, see [here](https://iangow.github.io/far_book/intro.html).

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)
library(DBI)

pg <- dbConnect(RPostgres::Postgres())

djones.djdaily <- tbl(pg, sql("SELECT * FROM djones.djdaily"))

data <- 
  djones.djdaily %>%
  select(date, dji) %>%
  collect(n = 10)

data
#> # A tibble: 10 × 2
#>    date         dji
#>    <date>     <dbl>
#>  1 1896-05-26  40.9
#>  2 1896-05-27  40.6
#>  3 1896-05-28  40.2
#>  4 1896-05-29  40.6
#>  5 1896-06-01  40.6
#>  6 1896-06-02  40.0
#>  7 1896-06-03  39.8
#>  8 1896-06-04  39.9
#>  9 1896-06-05  40.3
#> 10 1896-06-08  39.8
```

<sup>Created on 2023-02-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>